# How to count instances of <span> with a certain class in C#?

Tags: c#

```
args.Content;
```

Is dynamic.

On this example it has this value and it represents a script input:

```
<div class="b-db">
<span class="b-db-ac b-db-ac-th" role="button"></span>
<span class="b-db-ac b-db-ac-th" role="button"></span>
<span class="b-db-ac b-db-ac-th" role="button"></span>
<span class="b-db-ac b-db-ac-th" role="button"></span>
<span class="b-db-ac" role="button"></span>
</div>
```

How do you count number of instances of span with the class="b-db-ac b-db-ac-th"?

On this example output should be: 4

Comment: @Hammerstein Split on space? funny......

Answer (score 4):

When you are working with html, use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(DATA);

var count = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='b-db-ac b-db-ac-th']")
               .Count();
```

You can even use pure Linq

```
var count2 = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span")
                .Where(s => s.Attributes["class"]!=null && 
                            s.Attributes["class"].Value == "b-db-ac b-db-ac-th")
                .Count();
```

Comment: Can't use any external parser for this application, any suggestion ?

Comment: @sebas then your best bet would be Regex, but I wouldn't recommend it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @sebas Maybe you want to try `Regex.Matches(DATA, @"<span class=""b-db-ac b-db-ac-th""").Cast<Match>().Count();`

Comment: Thanks, but it's giving me an empty output

Comment: @sebas No it returns 4, Your test data may be different than the one you posted here. (BTW: `Count()` can not give an empty output, either a number or an exception)

Comment: Sorry i dont know regex, this returns the html input from my OP

(.*)

How can I use your regex code to output "4"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62636/discussion-between-sebas-and-ezi).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). You'll want to query specifically on the `b-db-ac-th` CSS class to get the 4 elements you requested in your question.

This code isn't meant to be copy/pasted but should give you the direction you need to accomplish what you're looking to do.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(args.Content);
var count = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span").Count( d=> d.Attributes["class"].Value == "b-db-ac b-db-ac-th" );
```

Comment: `HtmlDocument` doesn't have a property  `DocumentElement`

Comment: `This will allow you to use the CSS selectors to query your HTML` No, you can use XPath or Linq, not CSS selectors.

Comment: @EZI, updated the example code to use `DocumentNode` instead of `DocumentElement`.

Comment: you can use css Selectors with [Fizzler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/)